# SQL AVG and overall average of departments

Tags: sql, average

my data is like this

```
Dept  Sub_Dept  Sal
d1     sd1       100
d1     sd1       150
d1     sd2       100
d1     sd2       200
d1     sd2       350
d2     sd1       100
d2     sd1       250
d2     sd1       250
d2     sd2       200
d2     sd2       350
```

My output should be the count of each sub dept, the `AVG` of the Sal values of each sub department (`sub_dept`), and the `AVG` of all departments (dept)

I want my output to look like this

Result

```
d1         sd1 2  125
d1         sd2 3  200
Total          5  180
d2         sd1 3  200
d2         sd2 2  225
Total          5  230
grand total    10 205
```

How to get the inner and outer `AVG` values ?

Comment: Have you learned about `GROUP BY` yet?

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
select dept,sub_dept,count(*) cnt ,avg(Sal) as av
from table_name group by dept,sub
 union all
 select 'total','', count(*),avg(Sal) 
 from table_name
```

Comment: if we want to get overall counts avgs for each dept like mentioned below how to group by                                                                                                                                      d1     sd1       100
d1     sd1       150
d1     sd2       100
d1     sd2       200
d1     sd2       350
d2     sd1       100
d2     sd1       250
d2     sd1       250
d2     sd2       200
d2     sd2       350

Result
d1  sd1 2  125
d1  sd2 3  200
Total   5  180
d2  sd1 3  200
d2  sd2 2  225
Total   5  230
grand total 10 205

Comment: @Velpur please add in question not in comment btw the query that i provided is that work for your current problem

Answer (score 0):

Most dialects of SQL support the standard `grouping sets` (or at least `roll up`).  Typical syntax would be:

```
select dept, sub_dept, avg(sal)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (dept, sub_dept), () );
```